# Materials on proper use of English tense

Tags: tenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Could anyone suggest to me a good online source to help me with the concepts of English tense? I've tried searching with Google but haven't found anything. I'm looking for material which starts from the basics and gives a comprehensive review of the subject.

I am looking to learn about the correct usage of "have," "has," "had," "do," "does," "have been," "had been," etc.

Comment: I am always caught off-guard for a moment with this usage of "revise". For here it would mean to alter, and we would review in order to remind ourselves of what is already learnt. It is not a good reference for a quick brush-up on the subject, but Goold Brown's The Grammar of English Grammars is available on Project Gutenberg and has an amusing discussion on many things grammatical including the tenses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic English language learning site with a nice rundown on verb tenses: http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_sys-tenses.htm.