# How do the tens­es and as­pects in English cor­re­spond tem­po­ral­ly to one an­oth­er?

Tags: verbs, tenses, conditionals, progressive-aspect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

Non-na­tive speak­ers of­ten get con­fused about what the var­i­ous tens­es 
and as­pects mean in English. With in­put from some of the folk here I've
put to­geth­er a di­a­gram that I hope will pro­vide some clar­i­ty on the
mat­ter.

I of­fer it as the first an­swer to this ques­tion. Con­sid­er it a liv­ing
doc­u­ment. In­put is wel­come, and good sug­ges­tions will be 
in­cor­po­rat­ed in­to the di­a­gram.

---

**No­ta bene:** What this is *not* is a dis­cus­sion of whether there are 
more than two tens­es in English. [We have a ded­i­cat­ed ques­tion for
that](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/91130/300), to which this
ques­tion is not in­tend­ed to sup­ply ar­gu­ments one way or the oth­er. 
Here, the aim is to pro­vide an overview of what con­struc­tions
English-speak­ing peo­ple use for con­vey­ing in­for­ma­tion about ac­tions
re­fer­ring to past, present, and fu­ture, and to pro­vide it first and
fore­most to pre­cise­ly the peo­ple who are like­ly to use "tense" as a
catch-all term in their search, rather than to lin­guists who know bet­ter.

**Break­ing News** There is now an ex­cel­lent ELU blog ar­ti­cle ti­tled 
[How We Talk About Fu­ture
Si­t­u­a­tions](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2015/09/how-we-talk-about-future-situations/).
It is high­ly rec­om­mend­ed read­ing.

Comment: Tenses are confusing. Despite what you've heard, English only has two tenses: past and non-past. We have a wealth of periphrastic constructions which allow us to express aspect at all, and more specific tense.

Comment: @Jonathan: I understand what you are saying, but that is highly dependent on how you define the word "tense". Taking the meaning commonly ascribed to it by the majority of native speakers, it isn't true to say there are only two tenses (though I realise the word has a narrower meaning in linguistics); similarly with "periphrastic" - in the [technical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periphrasis) sense what you say is true, but not so with the [common meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periphrasis), since "I will go" is the shortest (standard) way of expressing that meaning :)

Comment: @Jonathan: (And whatever we call them - tenses, modals, auxiliaries, periphrastic constructions - many people come to this site looking for advice on how to use them :)

Comment: That's not our problem. If they come looking for eternal salvation, would you have us administer sacraments? Lying to students is the reason why we're in this mess to start with; there's no excuse for continuing the practice.

Comment: @JohnLawler What is it someone's been lying about? And what mess? Really hoping for some elucidation.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19471/when-to-use-has-lived-vs-lived-vs-had-lived

Answer (score 231, accepted):

A visualization of what we mean in English by the various tenses:

[image: A visualization of what we mean in English by the various tenses]

Comment: @JonPurdy: I'm not sure the question is about continuity; but it would be great if you could somehow fit that into the diagram as well!

Comment: Would it be possible to name the tenses? For example, "I had eaten (past perfect/pluperfect)".

Comment: I think this diagram fails to convey anything useful, except maybe for the notion of past and future, which is the last thing people are likely to have trouble with. It also lacks internal consistency: "I am eating" : "I have been eating" = "I was eating" : "I had been eating", yet there is no graphical correspondence.

Comment: I was thinking about how to capture the difference between simple tenses and continuous tenses.  The difference between "I ate" and "I was eating" is that "I ate" refers to a specific point (or points) in the past, while "I was eating" refers to something that was going on already: "I was eating when she walked in."  I made a [mockup](http://i.imgur.com/GDZrp.png) of some of the parts to show what I am talking about.  (I know that "I ate" can be 3 minutes ago, but the "point in the past" on the chart could be 3 minutes ago; it's arbitrary. The important thing is the relative differences.)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Another good point. I have the source file at home, so when I get off work I'll look at some more revisions.

Comment: @Robusto: It's hard to see where 'right now' matches up with some of your ranges. Can you put a vertical line there? Also, "I am eating" #1 should straddle that line, even from "a point in the past" to "a point in the future".

Comment: Excellent idea for helping students visualize these ideas. Perhaps the best thing about it is that it may help students really see how these "tenses" differ from their mother language. As all English teachers know, mother tongue interference, reinforced by grammar translation, is a major problem.

Comment: When we limit the subject to 'I', I think some "tense" uses get left out. "I eat at five" can *hardly* be glossed as anything but the habitual /routine. When, for example, we have, "We eat at five", there is the sense of present simple for that which is scheduled.

Comment: I think that it's problematic to suggest that 'will', and the variations on it, represents thee future tense. What of; be going to/be about to/present simple [mentioned]/intend to/aim to/ present continuous [noted in chart]. See Neil Coffey in, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20178/how-many-tenses-are-there-in-english-and-what-are-they

Comment: The present perfect is often used as a "near past", one distinct from the simple past.  This is more common in UK speakers than in North American ones, who are more apt to use the simple past even for very recent events.  Contrast ‘I’ve just started’ or ‘Have you eaten?’ with ‘I  just started’ or ‘Did you eat?’ in your own dialect. The perfect versions are nearer in time for some speakers, but indistinguishable for others. This distinction also occurs in Spanish, where Old World speakers will often choose the perfect for the near past, but New World speakers will choose just the simple past.

Comment: @Robusto, have you considered adding a legend (along left or right edge of diagram) with the names of the tenses the examples embody?

Comment: How about the various "past tenses" exemplified [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist)?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Ambitious, but interesting. If you want to rough them out, I'll add them to the graphic.

Comment: The point is that there are several thousand such constructions; I didn't even scratch the combinations. They can't all be tenses. In fact, none of them are tenses. That's why we say there are only two tenses in English.

Comment: OK, whatever you want to call them. This question and answer were designed to give non-native speakers some idea of what we mean when we speak of such combinations. Note that this question received input from several linguists, who were untroubled by the nomenclature.

Comment: I agree with John Lawler and have downvoted this answer. @Robusto I'm a linguist and am troubled by the nomenclature.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: I guess that's just one more piece of evidence that linguistics isn't settled science.

Comment: So is Creationism. Teach the controversy, eh?

Comment: @Robusto, Where will the tenses "I would eat", "I had been eaten", and "I have been eaten" fit in the diagram above?

Comment: @Pacerier: If you had been eaten, you wouldn't be around to worry about that.

Comment: You should sort the graphs: first separate past/present; then the aspect patterns would (mostly) be two copies {one set on the left=past, and a copy on the right=present}  Then you might repeat the whole thing for passive voice.   PS: your 'I will have been eating' bar is wrong.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure about all the details, but this answer is a thing of beauty.

Comment: The diagram is wrong for 'I will have been eating'. The orange bar should start after 'right now' and end before 'a point in the future'.

Comment: I found this is really interesting. Could you please upload the same diagram for passive voice if you have?

Comment: Hans Reichenbach also used diagrams to describe English tenses.  There are many discussions available, among them: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tense-aspect/#SpeTimEveTimRefTim

Comment: I don't mind you calling them all tenses, but this diagram is bad.  The progressives should all be 'dots', and the perfects should all end before a time marker, and only one past and one future time marker should be used.

Comment: Let's say that someone or something have/had been was brought back from somewhere just a moment ago. How should I tell this? "He had been brought back!"  or "He have been brought back!"? I don't see this fitting into any option from the diagram above :-( (I would go for "have", is this correct?)

Comment: There are three tenses (present, past and future), and two aspects (simple and perfect), which combine to form simple present, simple past, simple future, present perfect, past perfect and future perfect. Contrary to what many students are taught, we can disregard "continuous" as an aspect, because the verb-ing can be viewed as an adjective (present participle or past participle), therefore reducing the number of aspects. For example, in "I am running", "running" is an adjective, and thus the sentence is in the present tense, rather than the so-called "present continuous tense".

Comment: "A visualization of what we mean in English by the various tenses: A visualization of what we mean in English by the various tenses image" is not an answer but that's what users will hear when they use a screen reader. This answer needs to be updated to use appropriate alt text.

Comment: @Laurel: I'm not up on what would pass for appropriate alt text. If you supply the text, I'll be happy to update it. This is community wiki anyway, so ...

Comment: The diagram does not place the "tenses" on the timeline correctly. And the only way to explain them properly is using timelines.

Answer (score 79):

For the sake of presenting the information in another way:

### I eat

*habitually; in general.*

- *“I eat venison occasionally.”*

*as a command*

- *“Now, we eat!”*

### I am eating

*at this point; at this point, continuously; at a point in the future.*

- *“I am eating these leftovers. Would you like some?”*
- *“I am eating lunch with John on Thursday.”*

### I ate

*at a point in the past.*

- *“I ate squid once.”*
- *“I ate lunch early today.”*

### I was eating

*at a point in the past, continuously.*

- *“I was eating my dinner, when the phone rang.”*

### I have eaten

*at a point in the past; in the past in general.*

- *“I have eaten many different kinds of sushi.”*

### I have been eating

*up to and including now, continuously. = I was and am eating.*

- *“I have been eating the bread that's on the counter, not knowing it's mouldy.”*

### I had eaten

*before a point in the past.*

- *“I had eaten barbecue before, but this steak was better than any I'd ever tasted.”*

### I had been eating

*up to and including a point in the past, continuously.*

- *“I had been eating breakfast in bed, till I started seeing ants in my room.”*
- *“I had already been eating for fifteen minutes by the time she showed up.”*

### I will eat

*at a point in the future; in the future in general.*

- *“I will eat an apple a day from now on.”*
- *“I will eat dinner with you tomorrow if you want.”*

### I will be eating

*up to and including a point in the future, continuously.*

- *“I will be eating only a little bit of this cake. You can have the rest.”*

### I will have eaten

*before a point in the future.*

- *“I will have eaten by the time you get out of work, so we can't eat together.”*

### I will have been eating

*up to and including a point in the future, continuously.*

- *“I will have been eating a vegetarian diet for twenty years next month.”*

Comment: Feel free to flesh out the examples. I preferred a single verb for consistency.

Comment: Habituality is by no means the only use of the present indicative in English. For example, if I say "I am hungry" it means I am hungry right now, not as a habit. There are also other mistakes, but I'm posting too much.

Comment: The present indicative can also be used to describe things as they happen, e.g. a sports commentator: "Montana goes back to pass, and he's sacked at the 42 yard line."

Comment: @LaC: Oh, come on, *to be* is hardly a fair example. Besides, it's CW. Correct it.

Comment: I sit in my chair. I see a computer in front on me. On its screen, a message by @Jon Purdy claims I am being unfair. I disagree.

Comment: @LaC: Oh no, a slew of other verbs are totally valid examples, and my post is definitely simplified to the point of being incomplete. It's only *I am hungry* that I had a problem with, since you're using *to be* to introduce a predicate. Also, there's some colloquial (and facetious) use of *do be* to denote habitual states: *I do be hungry*; *the Pope does be Catholic*. But anyway, the point of making a post CW is that it can be continually improved. If I haven't done a good job, help me.

Comment: @JonPurdy, What about "I would eat"?

Answer (score 16):

My guess is that you read a table something like this:

- **Present Simple** (*I eat*)

  - habitually; in general.
  - as a command
- **Present Continuous** (*I am eating*

  - at this point
  - at this point, continuously
  - at a point in the future.
- **Past Simple** (*I ate*)

  - at a point in the past.
- **Past Continuous** (*I was eating*)

  - at a point in the past continuously
- **etc...**

and found it confusing.  Your first instinct (and it's a good one!) was to draw a diagram to make sense of it.  But the diagram is just as confusing as the table.

The problem is that our brains just don't work that way.  If you ask a typical native speaker to list all the situations where he uses a particular tense, mood & aspect, he'll find it impossible.  But if you show him a sentence and ask him to choose the correct tense, mood & aspect, he'll have no trouble.  In other words, our mental table of tenses and moods looks more like this:

- **habitually, generally**

  - *I eat cheese.*
- **habitually, in the past**

  - *I ate cheese.*
  - *I would eat cheese.*
- **making a request**

  - *Please eat cheese.*
  - *Could you eat cheese?*
  - *Would you mind eating cheese?*
  - *I was wondering whether you would eat some cheese?*
- **imaginary situation in the future**

  - *If I eat cheese, I will have cheese in my belly.*
- **imaginary situations in the past**

  - *I wish I had eaten cheese.*
- **etc.**

So if you want to make a diagram that is useful to learners of English, you need to take the same approach.  That's a tall order!  I don't even know that it's possible.  I'd love to know about any past attempts.

Comment: Actually, I just put it together by hand, with input from Kosmonaut and a few others. Of course it will never cover all possible use cases nor be eternally accurate to six decimal places. I intended it as a rough guide for non-native speakers, who may be surprised that, say, you can't indicate precisely that an action is currently being performed without use of the progressive. And so on.

Comment: A little late in my response, I know, but actually you **can** indicate actions taking place now. "I now pronounce you man and wife." "I write to inform you that ...." (arguably) "[I] Thank you." It's called *the performative*. Admittedly, it's not very common, but I think it reinforces the point I made in my earlier answer.

Answer (score 12):

One strange property of the perfect tense is that it refers to two times: the time in the past when the action was performed, and the time indicated by the auxiliary verb (to have). Depending upon usage, a sentence using the perfect tense can be more about the present (or the time of the auxiliary verb) than it is about the past:

```
A: Are you hungry?
B: I have eaten.
```

B implies he is not hungry because he is in the present condition of having eaten recently. This usage provides a way of talking about a current condition because of recent action.

```
A: Do you have homework?
B: I have graduated!
```

B implies he is now in the condition of never having homework because he graduated from school. The emphasis is on the present.

```
A: What did you do when you ran out of gas?
B: I had been a Boy Scout in my youth, so I was prepared and 
   had a small tank of gas in my trunk.
```

Although B might be foolish for keeping containers of flammable liquids in the tight confines of his trunk, his Boy Scout readiness existed at the time he ran out of gas.

Humans exist in a flux of ever-changing conditions often resulting from recent actions, and the perfect tense gives us an easy way to talk about them.

Comment: +1 and welcome to the site. This is a good answer, enough so that it probably deserves its own venue. I think you should maybe ask a separate question about perfect tenses, to which you would supply this answer. Yeah, you can do that.

Comment: Robusto, thanks. This is a much friendlier welcome than I had on the grammar board, where I was more accosted than greeted. Thanks.

Comment: What grammar board would that be? Not on the StackExchange network, surely.

Answer (score 9):

Your past perfect tense starts in the infinite past for any action, but it doesn't have to happen so. I include an illustration for the verb *see* in the past perfect from the following text, written around 2010, which is about a movie that was shelved in 1981, kept for two decades, but finally released around 2002. So, instead of two reference points on the timeline, there can be three.

- The story behind Ladies and Gentleman, The Fabulous Stains is a messy and complicated one. It was riddled with production problems, an editing process that took over a year to complete, and after all was said and done, Paramount Studios decided to shelf the film for over 20 years.  … Adler also took over a year to edit the film after shooting wrapped up, allegedly changing the ending several times. Once Ladies and Gentleman, The Fabulous Stains was completed, it was previewed at a few test screenings and the response was so poor that Paramount decided not to release it at all. Many of the cast and crew **hadn’t** even **seen** the film in its entirety after it was completed.

------------------------1981=========2002------NOW------------------------

Extra reference points can be included for some other tenses, but I leave that to the readers.

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget subjunctive/conditional:

> Ernie would eat that cookie if Bert were not watching him.
>
> Ernie would eat that cookie if Bert was not watching him.

The first is subjunctive: it implies Bert *is* watching Ernie, but if that weren't true, then Ernie would eat the cookie. Subjunctive tense is used when stating a condition that isn't true, but we are imagining an alternate reality.

The second is conditional (not sure if that's the right name): whether Bert was or wasn't watching Ernie is unknown.

The normal subject-verb agreement ("Bert was") gets tweaked to form subjunctive ("was" → "were").

Comment: Those are moods, not tenses.

Comment: @LaC: Couldn't "I will eat!" be considered a mood and not a tense?

Comment: @LaC: go figure, I could have sworn they were tenses. Either we were taught wrong or the name has changed or I'm just forgetting things ;-)

Comment: There's no difference in the way English grammar treats will/would/shall/should/can/could/may/might/must. However, when teaching English, it's awkward to say that these are all tenses, and it's awkward not to have a future tense. Thus, constructions with "will" are called tenses, and constructions with "would" are sometimes called tenses, and constructions with the other auxiliary verbs above are generally called moods.

Comment: I'm told that grammar is usually not taught in school in several English-speaking countries. That doesn't mean that grammar does not exist, or that it stops at syntax ("ok, it's all auxiliary verbs, let's go home"), or that it was constructed merely for the benefit of foreign learners. Tense, mood, aspect etc. are useful concepts in linguistics that apply across languages.

Comment: Now, to answer the question, "tense" refers to the time of the action (in fact, the word "tense" is just a fancy-pants way of saying "time"), while "mood" refers to one of several modes of use (to indicate fact, hypothesis, command, etc.). The two concepts are orthogonal: for instance, "I was" is past tense, indicative mood; "[if] I were [king]" is present tense, subjunctive mood; "[if] I had been [awake]" is past tense, subjunctive mood"; "I see [a cow in the field]" is present tense, indicative mood.

Comment: BTW, I had originally only read the first line of this answer. Now that I look at the rest, I must say it's completely wrong. In "Ernie would eat that cookie if Bert were not watching him", "would eat" is in conditional mood, "were not watching" is in subjunctive mood. In "Ernie would eat that cookie if Bert was not watching him", the subjunctive is replaced with the indicative, not to indicate any change in meaning, but simply because the subjunctive is usually identical to the indicative in English, and what few differences remain (eg "were") are being lost.

Comment: @Peter Shor: But there is a difference. 'will' is often defined for students as the future tense. I'm not suggesting that moods be called tenses, but they are qualifiers of those "tenses". How is 'will' any less a mood than 'might' in "I will go" v "I might go". 'will' does not guarantee going, it only expresses a personal feeling that the likelihood of going is 100%. Where is the cutoff point? Is "I almost certainly will go" close enough in epistemic meaning to qualify as a "tense"?

Comment: @LaC: I meant the latter half of each sentence, not the former. As for indicative/conditional... I can only blame my memory or my English teacher in 1989. Am I free to eat my hat now?

Comment: @LaC No, **‘If I were’ is *not* ‘present’ subjunctive!**  That’s ‘If I be’, and is not now used; see ‘lest I be’ for a contemporary example of the pr subj. ‘If I were’ is where a Romance speaker would use imperfect subjunctive, as in ‘Si  (yo) estuviese listo, me iría’ (If I were ready, I’d leave) in Spanish; notice ‘iría’ is in the conditional. What you mislabel past subjunctive is a compound tense, aligning then with ‘Si hubiese estado listo’ which is the pluperfect subjunctive in Spanish, because ‘had been’ has ‘had’ in the imperfect subjunctive and ‘been’ in the participle.

Comment: @tchrist: you're right, "if I were" is imperfect (but probably just called "past" in English) and "if I had been" is pluperfect.

Comment: Yes, you can think of a conjugation as a cell in a 5-dimensional matrix, the axes of which comprise person (1st, 2nd, 3rd), number (singular or plural), mood (indicative or subjunctive), voice (active or passive), and tense.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding present/past perfect continuous, e.g.:
*I have been reading* and
*I have read*
can both even be used in the same situation by the same person; the difference isn't always temporal:
*I have been reading since 3:00.*
*I have read 50 pages.*

The first emphasizes the action, and the second emphasizes the object, even if it is the same person saying both sentences *one right after the other*.
I also note that this diagram shows exactly the same for "I had eaten," and "I had been eating," but not for the "I have..." versions, presumably because you didn't want to add too many points in the past. But that surely won't help anyone differentiate between them.

I also use timelines to illustrate some of these, but not 12 of them at once. From a practical ESL point of view (incidentally), it's more helpful for most non-native speakers to get very comfortable with maybe 5 of these first, and the others will then start to make sense when they come up. Of course, that's not what they want to hear!